# Functions in different C++ classes

Tags: c++

So, I've started a course on C++, but I have a slight problem when it comes to functions with different classes.
I've learnt to create functions the following way:

```
string someFunction(){
return "blah";
}
```

However, with different classes it seems to be different.
I've tried the following and it didn't work:

(Startup.h)

```
#ifndef STARTUP_H
#define STARTUP_H
#include <string>

class Startup{
    public:
        Startup();
        string getBuild();
    };

#endif
```

(Startup.cpp)

```
#include "Startup.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string build;

Startup::Startup(){

    build = "1.0.0 Alpha";
    getBuild();

}

string Startup::getBuild(){

    cout << "The build is: " << build << endl;

}
```

(main.cpp)

```
#include "Startup.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    Startup startup;

    return 0;

}
```

The error message is:

> C:\Users\someone\Desktop\C++\Projects\Stuff\Startup.h|8|error: 'string' does not name a type|

*Also, I know I could just print out the build in the Startup function but I'm just experimenting right now.*

Comment: What "didn't work"?

Comment: What is the problem? You're not returning anything in your `getBuild()` function (you maybe wanted to make it return `void`?).

Comment: Apart from that, you're using everything the wrong way. Pick an introductory book.

Comment: "C:\Users\someone\Desktop\C++\Projects\Stuff\Startup.h|8|error: 'string' does not name a type|" is the error I am getting

Comment: @Arraying I've come across that issue a couple hundred times and can't figure it out. What is it?

Comment: @Arraying In the `.h` file you need to write `std::string` as you don't have the `using namespace std;` directive.

Comment: @VeniVidiVici just told me you need to write std::string (or using namespace std which is what I did).

Comment: @Arraying So, a function like that would have to be of type `std::string`?

Comment: @VeniVidiVici yeah, like this: 
    public:
        Startup();
        std::string getBuild();

Comment: @Arraying I've spent hours trying to figure that out! You've made my day! The only thing is that isn't `string` a variable type?

Comment: @VeniVidiVici pingul told me literally a few comments above, I'm a C++ noob so if you have any questions I suggest you ask someone else, sorry ;l

Answer (score 2):

The `string` class is in the `std` namespace. Use it like this:

```
class Startup{
    public:
        Startup();
        std::string getBuild();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your class as this:

```
#ifndef STARTUP_H
#define STARTUP_H
#include <string>

class Startup{
    public:
        Startup();
        std::string getBuild();
    };

#endif
```

Your code should work now. `getBuild` doesn't return anything, so give it a return type of `void`, in both definition and declaration.  Prepend `std::` to `cout` and `string` as well, explaining your error.

Comment: @dxiv sentence is removed.

Comment: The constructor calls `getBuild()`

Comment: wouldn't you need to skip startup.getBuild(); isn't Startup() a constructor hence it gets run automatically?

Comment: Error is fixed, finally

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in late here, but what you probably wanted is a combination of stuff:

In `.h`

```
#ifndef STARTUP_H
#define STARTUP_H
#include <string>

class Startup{
public:
    Startup();
    std::string getBuild();
  //^^^
private:
    std::string buildName; // store the variable inside the class instead
};

#endif
```

In `.cc`

```
#include "Startup.h"
#include <iostream>
// no need to include <string>, it was included previously

using namespace std; // This makes it so you don't have to write `std::` infront of `string` and `cout`

Startup::Startup(){
    build = "1.0.0 Alpha";
    cout << "The build is: " << getBuild() << endl;
}

// Kind of unnecessary function
string Startup::getBuild(){
    return buildName;
}
```